# Why is my white hair turning black/dark brown?

Tags: human-biology

The only change I have made is I started taking a multivitamin daily (centrum silver, men over 50) about a month ago....Now I see black hairs in my beard and on my head.  I was prematurely gray (started at age 20) and have been completely gray/white for the last 20 or so years. Just curious...